# How to extract new matrix from existing one

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large number of entries arranged in three columns. Sample of the data is:

```
A=[1 3 2 3 5 4 1 5 ; 
   22 25 27 20 22 21 23 27; 
   17 15 15 17 12 19 11 18]'
```

I want the first column (hours) to control the entire matrix to create new matrix as follows:

```
Anew=[1 2 3 4 5 ; 22.5 27 22.5 21 24.5; 14 15 16 19 15]'
```

Where the 2nd column of `Anew` is the average value of each corresponding hour for example:

from matrix `A`:
at hour 1, we have 2 values in 2nd column correspond to hour 1
which are 22 and 23 so the average is 22.5

Also the 3rd column: at hour 1 we have 17 and 11 and the
average is 14 and this continues to the hour 5 I am using Matlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) for this:

```
Anew = [unique(A(:,1)),...
        cell2mat(accumarray(A(:,1),1:size(A,1),[],@(x){mean(A(x,2:3),2)}))]
```

This uses the first column `A(:,1)` as indices (`x`) to pick the values in columns 2 and 3 for averaging (`mean(A(x,2:3),1)`). The curly brackets and the call to `cell2mat` allow you to work on both columns at once. Otherwise, you could do each column individually, like this

```
Anew = [unique(A(:,1)), ...
        accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,2),[],@mean), ...
        accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,3),[],@mean)]
```

which may actually be a bit more readable.

**EDIT**

The above assumes that there's no missing entry for any of the hours. It will result in an error otherwise. Thus, a more robust way to calculate `Anew` is to allow for missing values. For easy identification of the missing values, we use the `fillval` input argument to `accumarray` and set it to `NaN`.

```
Anew = [(1:max(A(:,1)))', ...
        accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,2),[],@mean,NaN), ...
        accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,3),[],@mean,NaN)]
```

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly to my 6000 by 4 matrix. only I changed numbers of the sample example to my real matrix. Thanks Jonas

Answer (score 2):

You can use [consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354) to do the work for you.

```
[Afinal(:,1),Afinal(:,2:3)] = consolidator(A(:,1),A(:,2:3),@mean);

Afinal
Afinal =
            1         22.5           14
            2           27           15
            3         22.5           16
            4           21           19
            5         24.5           15
```